# preg_replace regular expression HTML

Tags: regex, wordpress, tinymce, preg-replace

I am using shortcodes in WordPress. After each shortcode output (closing div) I got <br> (or <br />) tag.
trying to filter them out, but I don't know how. Generated HTML looks like

```
<div class="fullwidth"><!-- 1st shortcode-->
<div class="fullwidth-content">
  <!-- 2nd shortcode-->
  <div class="twocol-one"> content
  </div><br>
</div><br>
<!-- 3rd shortcode-->
<div class="twocol-second"> content
</div><br>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
</div><br>
```

seems BR is newline from **tinyMCE**. And I don't want loooong shotcode lines.

I am trying to use preg_replace but i cannot create correct $pattern.

Can you help me?

my function

```
function replace_br($content) {
$rep = preg_replace("/<\/div>\s*<br\s*\/?>/i", "</div>",$content);
return $rep; }
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_br');
```

not working.

While using
    `$rep = preg_replace("/\s*<br\s*\/?>/i", "",$content);` in function, all BRs are replaced.
Fine, but i want to replace only BRs after closing DIV tag.

`str_replace("</div><br>", "</div>", $content);` also not working.

What's wrong with my function?

No error returned.

Comment: Here we go again, and again, and again...

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your regex, it may be wordpress that formats the code after, check that. http://regex101.com/r/lL4uS3

Comment: welcome to wordpress. start your step debugger and find out exactly which filter functions is putting those <br> tags in in. then kill the filter ([my guess](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)). but beware, wordpress might break down because you removed a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in the first place, since you have to remove the tags.
You are doing it wrong because you're using regex for HTML (sometimes it's OKish).

Variation of regex you're using should suffice: <kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/142941)</kbd>

You should really consider using `DOMDocument` or similar:

```
$html = <<<HTML
...
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName('br');

$remove = [];
foreach($element as $item){
  $remove[] = $item;
}

foreach ($remove as $item) {
  $item->parentNode->removeChild($item); 
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

This would remove all of `br`, you would need to adjust the code work for your specs, but this should be a pointer.

Comment: I am not sure of using DOMDocument class

Comment: @hakre Thanks, you helped me a lot. 
It was WP filter, adding `<br />` after `[shortcode]` before doing shortcodes
so i filtered out Ps and BRs close to [shortcodes] 
    `    $shortcodes = join("|",array("myshortcode1", "myshortcode2", "another shortcodes"));
    // opening tag
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?[($shortcodes)(\s[^]]+)?](<\/p>|<br\s*\/?>)?/","[$2$3]",‌​$content);
    // closing tag $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?[\/($shortcodes)](<\/p>|<br\s*\/?>)?/","[/$2]",$rep);`

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative way to use regex
in your case

```
/(?<=<\/div>)(<br[\s\/]?>)/mg
```